# sequence in $l_{1}$ and $l_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Trying to solve a problem, I have reduced it to the following, which I do not know if it is true or not, or how to prove it:

> Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of $(l_{\infty}, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$, such that it is also a subset of $(l_{1}, ||\cdot||_{1})$. Let $(y_n)_{n\ge1}\in Y$ be a sequence with $y_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ wrt $||\cdot||_{\infty}$. Then $y_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ wrt $||\cdot||_{1}$.

The original problem is: Let $Y$ as above. Define $T:Y\rightarrow l_1$ by $T(x_1, x_2, \dots )= (x_2, x_3, \dots)$. I need to show that T is bounded. Using closed graph theorem I have reduced it to the above.

Comment: Could you state the original problem?

Comment: It is true, that follows from the open mapping theorem.

Comment: If $Y$ is such a subspace then since $\|\cdot\|_\infty ≤ \|\cdot \|_1$ it must also be closed in $\ell^1$. Then the map $Y_\infty\to Y_1$ is a continuous bijective linear map between Banach spaces, hence an isomorphism. But I do not think any infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^1$ is isomorphic to any infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell^\infty$, meaning $Y$ must be finite dimensional.

Comment: @s.harp: Why must it be closed in $\ell^1$?

Comment: @tomasz if $y_n\in Y$ is Cauchy in $\ell^1$ then it must also be Cauchy in $\ell^\infty$ by the inequality between the norms. Since $\ell^1, \ell^\infty$ are complete $y_n$ must admit a limit in both spaces, but this limit must also agree with the pointwise limit of the components of $y_n$, hence the two possible limits must be equal, so the limit lies in $Y$ by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ closedness.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you be a little bit more explicit, please? I feel like I'm missing something since I've used closed graph theorem (which itself follows from OMT) to arrive at this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $j \colon l_1 \to l_{\infty}$ is continuous: For $x \in l_1$ we have
$$\lVert x\rVert_{\infty} = \max \: \{ \lvert x_n\rvert : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \leqslant \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_n\rvert = \lVert x\rVert_1 \tag{1}$$
(for $x \in l_1$, even $x \in c_0$, the supremum of $\lvert x_n\rvert$ is attained, hence we can use $\max$ here).

Therefore $j^{-1}(Y) = Y \cap l_1 = Y$ is closed in $l_1$. Thus $Y$ is a Banach space under the restriction of the $l_1$-norm as well as under the restriction of the $l_{\infty}$-norm to $Y$. These two norms are comparable [see $(1)$], hence by the open mapping theorem they are equivalent.

From the equivalence of the two norms, the desired conclusion follows immediately.

---

It is worth noting that such a subspace must be finite-dimensional (which yields another proof of the equivalence of norms). Indeed, analogous to the argument above, $Y$ is a closed subspace of $l_p$ for all $p < \infty$, in particular for $p = 2$. Now recall that $F \colon l_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to L^2(S^1,\sigma)$, where $\sigma$ is the normalised Haar measure, given by
$$F(x) = t \mapsto \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} x_n e^{int} \tag{2}$$
is an isometric isomorphism. It doesn't matter whether we identify $l_2(\mathbb{N})$ with $l_2(\mathbb{Z})$ via a bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ or view it as a subspace via the natural inclusion, either way $F(Y)$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(S^1,\sigma)$. And since $Y \subset l_1$, $(2)$ converges absolutely and uniformly for all $y \in Y$, whence $F(Y) \subset C(S^1) \subset L^{\infty}(S^1,\sigma)$.

By a theorem of Grothendieck (Theorem 5.2 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*), $F(Y)$ is finite-dimensional. Since $F$ is injective, it follows that $Y$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Is the situation of the question possible? Do such $Y$ exist that are not finite dimensional? I know almost nothing about subspaces of $\ell^p$, but I would have thought an $\ell^\infty$ like subspace of $\ell^1$ is impossible.

Comment: @s.harp I don't know if a subspace $Y$ as in the question can be infinite-dimensional. I suspect it can't be, but I have no immediate idea how to prove or refute that. However, the question doesn't require $Y$ to be infinite-dimensional, so it's definitely possible (all finite-dimensional subspace of $l_1$ work).

Comment: @s.harp Such a $Y$ must be finite-dimensional, see the addition to the answer.